# how to use oAuth for protecting the api calls

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am building an AngularJS application.I am looking for authentication of the api calls for few days, but I have not got how to start with it and use it.

I found OAuth 2.0 as a kind of default authentication, also used by Facebook and Twitter and so more. A lot of tutorials I found are about using OAuth 2.0 with Facebook and Twitter or Google where i don,t understood much . But, I do not want to authenticatie a user with Facebook, but I want to build my own authentication, using the user credentials in my own database. So I guess, I need my own OAuth provider.

The authentication has to be very secure and easy to connect for other companies, who want to use our data (it is a web application for book publisher).

Please point to some post or demo where there is some step by step procedure to do it 
I am using Angularjs,mongodb,nodejs ang passport in the application

Comment: check this tutorial http://aleksandrov.ws/2013/09/12/restful-api-with-nodejs-plus-mongodb/ it is quite old but describe how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer,why do we need  httpie which is specified in the post and also can u please suggest me a source which involves only oauth integration for the existing app. I found post specified contains too optimized code  due to which i am finding difficult to follow i am new bee please help

Comment: author of that article used httpie for fast testing in console (making requests), he could use curl. I prefere to write automated tests (mocha + superagent).
Maybe docs of oauth2orize be more helpful for you? https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2orize
There are methods how to create server and how to use it.